# An ordered field has no smallest positive element

Tags: ordered-fields

Prove that every ordered field has no smallest positive element.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ( "Use", "Prove") to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Suppose that $x$ is the smallest positive element. Show that $1/2$ is positive, and thus $x/2$ is positive. Thus $0<x/2<x$, a contradiction.

Comment: A few questions about this. What if the field is finite or has finite characteristic?

Comment: A field with finite characteristic can never be ordered, as we would then have $$1<1+1<1+1+1<\cdots<0$$

Comment: I understand that we are trying to prove this by a contradiction. With that i understand why we are letting x be the smallest positive element. What I don't understand is how you show 1/2 is positive and then from that show x/2 is positive. Can you expand a little more please.

Comment: @waltermiller: $1$ must be positive, since $1=1^2$; since $1$ is positive, $1+1$ is positive. Since $1+1$ is positive, $\frac{1}{1+1}$ is positive.